# Cannot import from 'com.google'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-analytics, libgdx

I'm struggling for hours and hours to get Google Analytics working on my Android app with libgdx. I have tried many things.

When I run the samples are finding `com.google`, but I can't seem to get it working for my libgdx project.

I linked the dependencies, installed them in the SDK, and graddle builds successfully. Yet, not finding the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

I needed to do a Clean build and Rebuild. That was all!